# Cutting a range and PasteSpecial formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to cut a range of cells and then paste the same range one cell over.  When I run this basic code, it still gives me Run-time Error 1004 Application or object-defined error.  Why am I getting this error?  Would this require an array instead?

```
Sub Cut_Paste
    Range("D4:F8").Cut
    Range("E4:G8").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
End Sub
```

Comment: You can test this yourself from a worksheet but paste special options are only available if you copy rather than cut. You could copy and then clear the original cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like that:

```
Sub Cut_Paste
    Range("D4:F8").Cut Destination:=Range("E4:G8")    
End Sub
```

Comment: It is not PasteSpecial method using

Answer (score 0):

Copy the larger range using only the top-left cell of the destination then Clear.

```
Sub Cut_Paste
    with Range("D4:F8")
        .copy
        Range("E4").PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulas
        .clear
    end with
End Sub
```

Comment: I apologize, I had to edit the question, the FillRight/Clear function only seems to work with single column ranges, I need to move a 3 column range.  Can this code work with larger than one column ranges?

Comment: Probably best to go back to a PasteSpecial then but you only need the top-left corner of the destination. This removes bad destination range calculation from consideration.

Comment: I think it will work if I just use the copy, then pastespecial, then clear the first column of the original copy range.